# Can you not select option by assigning value attribute to select element?

Tags: html, forms

I've select element like this

```
<select name='type'>
   <option value='1'> 1 </option>
   <option value='2'> 2 </option>
   <option value='3'> 3 </option>
</select>
```

on backend I want to select a value, like so.

```
<select name='type' value='2'>
   <option value='1'> 1 </option>
   <option value='2'> 2 </option>
   <option value='3'> 3 </option>
</select>
```

This should have selected 2nd option, but it doesn't.

Does this not happen or is something else is wrong.

Chrome/windows

**Edit**

Had to go with boolean route, i was using pug/jade so it ended up like this

```
select#expiry(name="days")
    option(value="7" selected=days=="7") 7 Days
    option(value="14" selected=days=="14") 1 week
    option(value="30" selected=days=="30") 1 Month
    option(value="90" selected=days=="90") 3 Months
    option(value="180" selected=days=="180") 6 Months
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No you cannot: [there is no value attribute on the select element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).**

The value of a `select` control is determined by the selected `option` child element's `value` attribute.

You can select an option by adding a `selected` [boolean attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes) to an option element is the source code.

```
<select name="type">
    <option value="1" selected="selected"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
    <option value="3"> 3 </option>
</select>
```

This can also be done dynamically via JavaScript.

```js
var selectElement = document.getElementById('my-select');
selectElement.value = 2; // selects the second option
                         // even though the first one
                         // is selected in the HTML
```

```html
<select name="type" id="my-select">
        <option value="1" selected="selected"> 1 </option>
        <option value="2"> 2 </option>
        <option value="3"> 3 </option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this:

```
<select name='type'>
   <option value='1'> 1 </option>
   <option value='2' selected> 2 </option>
   <option value='3'> 3 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: yea on backend i'd have to write n if conditions like so `if (val=='2') selected`

Comment: Correct. Or you could assign the value using JavaScript.